# Unfortunately (app name) has stopped

Tags: android, eclipse

I am totally new to android. I have an extremely limited knowledge of code. When I attempt to run the application on my android device it comes up with the message "unfortunately (app name) has stopped" please can some body inform me on how to fix this

This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.benchaful.newboard"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">


<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="com.benchaful.newBoard"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
</application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

My main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.benchaful.newboard"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:id="@+id/home_layout"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="#000000"
         >
```

There are some buttons here

```
<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/accesskey"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100px"
/>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.benchaful.newboard"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="#ffffff"
              android:gravity="bottom"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/home_layout"
              >
```

And this is my logcat

```
06-05 16:32:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(9665): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 16:32:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(9665): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.benchaful.newboard/com.benchaful.newBoard}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.benchaful.newBoard
06-05 16:32:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(9665):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2045)
06-05 16:32:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(9665):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146)
06-05 16:32:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(9665):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
06-05 16:32:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(9665):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
06-05 16:32:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(9665):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-05 16:32:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(9665):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-05 16:32:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(9665):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
06-05 16:32:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(9665):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 16:32:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(9665):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-05 16:32:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(9665):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
06-05 16:32:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(9665):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
06-05 16:32:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(9665):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 16:32:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(9665): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.benchaful.newBoard
06-05 16:32:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(9665):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
06-05 16:32:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(9665):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-05 16:32:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(9665):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-05 16:32:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(9665):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
06-05 16:32:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(9665):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2036)
06-05 16:32:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(9665):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the full name of your Activity? Your manifest has this:

`<activity android:name="com.benchaful.newBoard" ... >`

but "com.benchaful.newBoard" is your package name.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are defining your package and Class both as

```
com.benchaful.newboard
```

Do you have a class within that package that you want to start your main activity with?  If you do have this class, it would be helpful to see that too posted.