# Error: caused by: java.lang.Classnotfoundexception

Tags: android, eclipse

I am extremely new to coding, this is my first app. It is very frustrating that when running said app on a device or an emulator the "Unfortunately, app name has stopped" error came up. I believe that (by looking at the LogCat) I have pinpointed the problem to the error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException". Please can somebody tell me how I can fix this.

This is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.benchaful.newboard"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">


<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="com.benchaful.newBoard.activity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
</application>
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="16" android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

This is my main layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.benchaful.newboard"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollview1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:id="@+id/home_layout"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="#000000"
 >
```

There is some buttons here

```
<WebView 
android:id="@+id/accesskey"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="100px"
/>


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.benchaful.newboard"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="#ffffff"
          android:gravity="bottom"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/home_layout"
          >
        <com.google.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/libs/com.google.ads"
                             android:id="@+id/adView"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             ads:adUnitId="a151a7cc8c54403"
                             ads:adSize="BANNER"
                             />
</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my LogCat

```
06-07 16:35:58.128: E/AndroidRuntime(5925): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-07 16:35:58.128: E/AndroidRuntime(5925): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.benchaful.newboard/com.benchaful.newBoard.activity.ComponentInfo}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.benchaful.newBoard.activity.ComponentInfo
06-07 16:35:58.128: E/AndroidRuntime(5925):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2045)
06-07 16:35:58.128: E/AndroidRuntime(5925):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146)
06-07 16:35:58.128: E/AndroidRuntime(5925):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
06-07 16:35:58.128: E/AndroidRuntime(5925):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
06-07 16:35:58.128: E/AndroidRuntime(5925):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-07 16:35:58.128: E/AndroidRuntime(5925):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-07 16:35:58.128: E/AndroidRuntime(5925):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
06-07 16:35:58.128: E/AndroidRuntime(5925):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-07 16:35:58.128: E/AndroidRuntime(5925):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-07 16:35:58.128: E/AndroidRuntime(5925):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
06-07 16:35:58.128: E/AndroidRuntime(5925):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
06-07 16:35:58.128: E/AndroidRuntime(5925):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-07 16:35:58.128: E/AndroidRuntime(5925): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.benchaful.newBoard.activity.ComponentInfo
06-07 16:35:58.128: E/AndroidRuntime(5925):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
06-07 16:35:58.128: E/AndroidRuntime(5925):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-07 16:35:58.128: E/AndroidRuntime(5925):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-07 16:35:58.128: E/AndroidRuntime(5925):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
06-07 16:35:58.128: E/AndroidRuntime(5925):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2036)
```

Comment: You've literally posted the same question 4 times
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988058/error-caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970403/caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944315/unfortunately-app-name-has-stopped
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989139/android-error-caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line from your `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout`

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.benchaful.newboard"
```

Answer (score 0):

Package and class names are case-sensitive, check how you wrote "newboard"/"newBoard"